# Why does calling children of KtFile trigger NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: kotlin, nosuchmethoderror, psi

I have the following code that calls `children` of the `KtFile`. When I go inside the definition of this `children`, I can see that it is defined in `package com.intellij.psi` under the method called `getChildren()` which returns an array of `PsiElement`.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.*

fun KtFile.getFunctionList(): List<KtNamedFunction> {
    val functionList = mutableListOf<KtNamedFunction>()
    children.forEach {
        if (it is KtNamedFunction) functionList.add(it)
    }
    return functionList
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.intellij.psi.PsiElement[] org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.getChildren()'
    at docGenerator.KtParserKt.getFunctionList(KtParser.kt:36)
    ...
```

Why is this happening?